# Convergence of an infinite series that is split?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

If I split an infinite sequence in two. For instance: $\sum (a_{n} + b_{n}) = \sum a_{n} + \sum b_{n}$. If $\sum a_{n}$ and $\sum b_{n}$ are both convergent series, does that mean $\sum (a_{n} + b_{n})$ is also convergent?

Comment: Apply cauchy criterion to show partial sums satisfy it by the triangle inequality

Answer (score 1):

Definitely! This is one of the properties that comes under the name "arithmetic/algebra of limits".

Answer (score 0):

A series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ converges, by definition, if the limit of the partial sums,
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$$
converge (as sequences) to some limit $L$. We denote $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k = L$ in this case.

If we have two series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$, with respective partial sums
\begin{align}
S_n &= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k, \\
T_n &= \sum_{k=0}^n b_k,
\end{align}
then the partial sums for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k + b_k)$ are
$$R_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (a_k + b_k) = \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\right) + \left(\sum_{k=0}^n b_k\right) = S_n + T_n,$$
by commutativity of addition. If both $S_n$ and $T_n$ converge to limits $L$ and $M$ respectively, then $R_n = S_n + T_n$ converges to $L + M$, by the algebra of limits (two convergent sequences sum to a convergent sequence; this is proven using the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of a limit). Thus, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k + b_k)$ converges and
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k + b_k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k + \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k.$$